# Android - How to use Toast,AlertDialog...in a class that extends from Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I need to use a `Toast`, `AlertDialog`, and others, in a class that extends  `Fragment`. How do I it ?

```
public class TelaCONTATO extends Fragment{
Activity activity = getActivity();
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.telacontato, container,false);        

    return rootView;
}
public void clique(View v){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cliquei", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Comment: what's exactly the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the application's context if for some reason you can't get it with `getActivity`:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cliquei", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

---

I noticed that you're calling `getActivity` when the fragment is instantiated:

```
Activity activity = getActivity();
```

This will always lead to `activity` being `null`, because the fragment is not yet attached to an `Activity` when it's being instantiated.

Comment: @Blackbelt The OP didn't specify his exact problem but I'm guessing it's connected to the fact that `getActivity` will return `null` if the fragment is not yet attached to an activity.

Comment: @Simas, it's gives an error. getApplicationContext()stay red in my project.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you show a dialog and a toast:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
dialog.show();


Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
```

Comment: McGee... I used it but it gives an error: "Unfortunately, Unipharmus has stopped".

Comment: Yes. See my project: goo.gl/pm5dIC

Comment: Can you please post the error that is displayed in logcat?

Comment: You should be able to put the toast example directly into your onCreateView();

Comment: See the printscreen: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9uJGpEj3kYManhTYVZFSnV3TDA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yessss McGee... I wrote the Toast on the onCreateView(0; and it worked!! Thanks..